# Spring Integration DSL: how to make single-threaded caching channel?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-integration

I have the following flow config:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow setupDatabaseFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(pubSubDatabaseRabbitOutput)
          // WHAT CHANNEL
            .handle((p, h) -> databaseActivator.recordToDatabase(p, h))
            .get();
}
```

and I am willing to insert in "WHAT CHANNEL" place some channel, that is

- caching
- single-threaded
- running in separate thread

What would be the best channel specification to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what is the use-case, but that can be achieved with the `QueueChannel` and `PollingConsumer` with the `fixedDelay` policy.

1. `QueueChannel` uses queue buffer (persistent or in-memory) to keep messages until they are consumed. A-la cache in your terms.
2. The `PollingConsumer` does the poll from the queue using `TaskScheduler`, therefore separate thread.
3. Using `fixedDelay` policy you ensure that the next polling task won't start until the previous has been finished. Therefore single-threaded model.

If you don't like to sleep in between polling task, and end up with the event-driven model, you can use `fixedDelay(-1)`, this way the next polling task won't sleep after the previous. The current polling task does block the thread until the value in the queue.

**UPDATE**

Some code on the matter:

```
.channel(c -> c.queue())
.<Object>handle((p, h) -> databaseActivator.recordToDatabase(p, h), 
            e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(0).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
```

Comment: Thank you Artem, what would be the expression to place that channel in the flow? :)

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Though I got Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: period must not be negative  at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:92) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]

Comment: Oh! Sorry. right, that must be `0`, `-1` I meant for the `receiveTimeout()`